# System.TypeLoadException in Unknown Module with SQL Server CE

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I have a C# windows mobile application originally created in VS2005 that was used to create
a test database. However, now that I've included the C# code into a VS2008
project and re-setup the SQL references, I receive the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
Unknown Module.

Additional information: File or assembly name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe,
Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3BE235DF1C8D2AD3', or one of
its dependencies, was not found.

The reference path appears to be good. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: have you dropped and readded the reference ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Dropping and adding the reference yields the same results.

Answer (score 5):

Try to drop and readd the Reference.

A quick glance at my own GAC shows that library to have an incorrect PublicKeyToken

```
Assembly:         System.Data.SqlServerCe
Culture:          Neutral
Version:          3.5.0.0
Public Key Token: 89845dcd8080cc91
```

After a quick google, it looks like your referencing the desktop platform version instead of the device platform version.

See this post here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/f509138c-8442-4bef-916a-a97bda4721ee

> Running Sql Mobile applications on the desktop is not a supported scenario
>   (except your desktop is a TabletPC).
>
> The public key token for System.Data.SqlServerCe (desktop platform) is 3be235df1c8d2ad3
>
> The public key token for System.Data.SqlServerCe (device platform) is 89845dcd8080cc91

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your project to be a .Net Compact Framework 3.5 project? I imagine that if it is still being loaded as a 2.0 project it would have problems loading assemblies from the 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your problem is that you can load the named assembly but one of it's dependencies is still referenced as the 2.0 version from the previous project setup.
Go through all your referenced assemblies and make sure they are all from the same version of the framework. (That's actually not a requirement that they all are from the same version but it does make life easier in the long run). The problem is that if you use a v3.5 that will have v3.5 dependencies and if you only refrerence the v2.0 assembly you'll get the above error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was to completely remove the following from the  Pocket PC device:

```
<MY APP>
Microsoft .Net CF 3.5 EN-String R...
Microsoft .Net CF 3.5
SQLServerCompact 3.5 Tools EN
SQLServerCompact 3.5 Repl
SQLServerCompact 3.5 Core
```

Then installing:
    NETCFv35.ppc.armv4.cab  ( Microsoft .Net CF 3.5 )
    NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab ( Microsoft .Net CF 3.5 EN-String R... )
    sqlce.ppc.wce4.armv4.CAB ( SQLServerCompact 3.5 Core )

You might be able to just remove and reinstall the SQLServerCompact 3.5 packages. That is what worked for me.